# Insert list of children from parent object

Tags: apex

Why is below code not possible

```
Parent__c myparent = new parent__C();
myparent.child__r = new list<child__c>();
```

when i try to execute this,i am getting a compile error.,field is not writable.

where am i going wrong?(Code source is salesforce apex podcast)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the podcast you mentioned? Usually you would get the child__r list via a SOQL query or insert the list of child objects using an external id from the parent. See [Bob Buzzard Blog - Create Parent and Child Records in One Insert Call](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.nz/2012/03/create-parent-and-child-records-in-one.html)

Comment: I got it from Itunes.and it is mentioned in Records in database -ep009

Comment: That Bob Buzzard has some great things.

Answer (score 2):

The notation "**myparent.child__r**" is used while retrieving from query/displaying in a page.
An object will be a ***child*** when it has a link to parent record through ***id***. So your parent record has to inserted first and get the Id. Create your child records and set Master-detail field value to the Id.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign the child list reference.  If you really want to add to it you can add to the list itself (see below). Note that doing so will not actually save to the DB.  To affect the actual relationship in the DB you need to set the Lookup (or possibly M/D) field on the child itself and insert/update/upsert the child(ren).

The following will work, but if you save myparent its child__r list will go away immediately.

```
Parent__c myparent = new parent__C();
List<Child__c> children = myParent.child__r.add(new Child__c(Name='Abc'));
```

It might not be the most obvious way of coding it, however, if you have an existing parent in the DB you could technically do the following:

```
List<Child__c> children = myParent.child__r.add(new Child__c(Name='Abc', Parent__c = myparent.Id));
```

Then `upsert myparent.child__r;`.  However after that update you would want to query back out the Parent__c and its children.

Comment: Did you ever get code similar to this to run? I have been struggling with adding an object to a child list, but have yet to do so successfully. Also, in you example here, the return type of the list add() method is void, so the assignment to a list isn't valid.